# Jquery $.post doesnt post data

Tags: php, jquery

I try to post data from jQuery to the PHP file like this:

```
$("#I-like-it").click(function() {
    $.post(
        "stuff.php", {
            index_id: 313,
            hello: "my friend"
        }
    );
});
```

That's what stuff.php got in the $_POST:

```
array(0) { }
```

PHP file:

```
<?php

echo var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

What the hell Am i doing wrong? I spent 2 hours and testing code but my brain is overheated right now. Im done.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add last part of code, just after: PHP file:

Comment: Can you show us what's in your stuff.php file?

Comment: Where is stuff.php located in relation to the current file?

Comment: There was a php file but I didnt mark it as code and disappeared :d

Comment: Just to eliminate some possibilities, is your click handler correctly called?

Comment: Yes, click work properly. Alerts working after click.

Comment: Open your dev console and click the networking tab. Once your in there click your item and see if a request gets sent.

Comment: Well Bioto, result is: array(2) { ["index_id"]=> string(3) "313" ["hello"]=> string(9) "my friend" }

Comment: But still php has Array(0) { } :C

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#I-like-it").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "stuff.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { index_id: 313,
                hello: "my friend"
        }
    }).done(function(response){
      // handle response
    });
});
```

Check this out jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: hmm i don't understand what is wrong in your code..
var_dump of php function return void type, but it isn't problem for echo..
try exchange var_dump function to print_r, and you don't need echo these functions..
do you do good link for that php file?

Answer (score -2):

Can you try something?

PHP File:

```
<?php

echo 'test';

?>
```

JS:

```
$("#I-like-it").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('stuff.php', function(data) {
        console.log('data', data);
    })
});
```

Comment: why to use `getJSON`?

Comment: Just nothing happens.